# Autoclose an iframe with video with video.js if not click on play button

Tags: iframe, video.js

I want to autoclose an iframe with a video after 5 sec but if the user click on to play the video i want to ignore this condition, i have got already an event to autoclose the iframe when the video ends after 5 sec using this

```
player.on('ended', function() {
         setTimeout(function (), 5000);
  });
```

**Thanks**

Comment: Added one more tag

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to reset the time out?
Hope [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp) will help.